# How to find where API Values of Global Picklist are used in Salesforce?

Tags: picklist, global-picklist

Is there a script I can use or a way to search all of Salesforce to find where an API is used?

I need to update a global picklist, and don't want to run into any issue after updating the field label and API name.

Answer (score 3):

You can go to Field and click on where it is used button and all the references will be listed.

[image: Where is this used?]

Just be mindful of the fact that if that field name is used as a string in some query then it will not be fetched. If you have such scenario then you can try any text editor Find functionality and run the search operation over a whole codebase.

Comment: As Balwinder mentioned, a simple search (using search button) in VS Code can help in this matter, assuming your entire meta data is present locally. This way you might not have write any complex query but still be able to find most of the places.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answer, you can use the Tooling API to query the [MetadataComponentDependency](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_metadatacomponentdependency.htm) table to find hard dependencies. As mentioned before, soft dependencies using Dynamic Apex, JavaScript, etc cannot necessarily be detected with any API. Regression testing is advisable after making your changes and before deploying to production.